# A binary strings combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, permutations, combinations, binary

Suppose, there is a primary set with 2 binary strings: `{0000,0011}`.

I want to know the number of elements in a set that has all the elements that are an HD of 2,4 away from **each** of the elements in the primary set.

For 0011, there are $(4C_2+4C_3+4C_4)$= 11 elements that are **HD** of 2,3,4 away.

However, only 8 of the strings as shown below satisfy both these strings: `0000,0011`.

```
{0101, 0110, 1001, 1010, 1100, 1110, 1101, 1111}
```

Comment: "\${}_4C_2\$" for ${}_4C_2$.

Comment: I would like to attack the problem, but I don't know what "elements that are HD of 2,3,4 away" means.

Comment: HD= Hamming Distance.

Comment: @zzzzzazaza : So improve the Question by declaring and defining your notation and abbreviations.

Comment: @EricTowers good point.  However, I still awarded +1 to this query: interesting question, nice work shown, nice presentation.

Comment: Commenting, rather than answering, since analysis superficial.  In first example, two primary elements (denote as $a,b$) have HD = 2.  Further, given any 3rd element $x$, HD with either primary must be $\in \{0,1,2,3,4\}.$ Also, (odd/even) parity of HD$(x:a)$ must match parity of HD$(x:b)$.  Finally, start with original enumeration re element $a$ of $R = \binom{4}{2}, S = \binom{4}{3}, T =   \binom{4}{4}.$  When comparing elements represented by each of $R,S,T$ with HD against $b$, none of the $T$'s can be eliminated.  Further, exactly one of the $R$'s will be eliminated.   ...see next comment

Comment: It is also easy to see, that of the $\binom{4}{3} S$'s, only the two elements that happen to change both slots represented by the HD$(a:b) = 2$ will have the HD$(x:b)$ go from 3 to 1.  So, this explains why there were $2 + 1$ elements eliminated.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I wonder if there is a general formula that could be extended to the second example in the question, and later to any bit-strings with an arbitrary number of elements in the primary set.

Comment: Also, about this line ---> Further, given any 3rd element x, HD with either primary must be ∈{0,1,2,3,4}----> Sorry that I didn't make this clear earlier, for new members in the primary list, the criteria is that the HD must be 2 with the original members in the set.

Comment: I've gone as far as I *superficially* can.  Going further would require real work on my part.